# javascript having problems with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

having problems with regex in javascript.

need to parse out all variables from a String which include a letter.

As far i used `/[0-9\][A-Za-z.]*/g` gives me wrong results.

Sample:

```
windo.w029384-(2*I00983.size)+23.8/6+ss-t
```

need to parse out `windo.w029384, I00983.size, ss, t`

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
'windo.w029384-(2*I00983.size)+23.8/6+ss-t'.match(/[a-z][\w.]*/ig);
//=> ["windo.w029384", "I00983.size", "ss", "t"]
```

Comment: I think `/[a-z][\w.]*/ig` would be more concise and better suited since variables can definitely use underscores and the OP is simply trying to detect variables. What about the alternate form of `var.key`, `var["key"]` or `var['key']`, or even `var[key]`?

Comment: Totally agree on `\w` but for other forms of input OP needs to specify more examples.

Answer (score 0):

How about `/[\w.]+/g`?
`\w` includes [0-9] and [A-Za-z]